# SMTP not working for Comments Email Notifications

Tags: email, notifications, smtp

The problem is that I'm not receiving wordpress emails except the ones generated by sucuri plugin. I want admin to receive email notification on every new comment and post updates. 
Previously, my testing site was placed on bytehost.com where the default wordpress mailer worked just fine, used to send sucuri plugin emails and comments notification emails. Now as our official site host does not allow to use PHPmailer, so the default setting wont work. 
I have install Email SMTP for configuration, and it kinda worked only for sucuri plugin emails but not for comments.

Please help me with the configuration settings. I have already updated host and port of our server in SMTP plugin. 
Also as the server is our own, so there is no Cpanel.
All I have got is host and port. I'm seeking guidance with class-phpmailer.php is it needs to be configured
If you want any file to be pasted, please ask and help me with this issue.

Comment: maybe try an smtp plugin that has logging and/or diagnostics (like post-stmp) - otherwise it is really anyone's guess without the debug info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added host settings in class-phpmailer file i.e host = (my host address); and set 
TLS=true; 
and in pluggable file i replaced 
mailer = isMail(); 
with
mailer = isSMTP();

and now am receiving emails for comments. Hope this helps other people with the same issue.

Comment: never ever ever ever modify core files